# Is it possible to do inheritance for DTOs in NestJs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, inheritance, nestjs, dto

I have a NestJs Get controller which searches for a list of employees.

```
@Controller('employee')
export class EmployeeController {
    private logger = new Logger('EmployeeController');
    constructor(private employeeService:EmployeeService){}

    @Get()
    @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
    getEmployees(
        @Query() filter:GetEmployeesFilterDto
    ):Promise<Employee[]>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(filter), filter.batch);
        return this.employeeService.getEmployees(filter);
    }
}
```

In order to support pagination, the method accepts a filter DTO to accept parameters such as batch size and page number. Seeing as how this will be common parameters for other DTO classes, I thought of creating a base filter DTO:

```
export class BaseQueryFilterDto{

    @IsOptional()
    @IsInt()
    @UsePipes(ParseIntPipe)
    batch:number;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsInt()
    @UsePipes(ParseIntPipe)
    skip:number;

}
```

And then inherit this DTO for the GetEmployeesFilterDto:

```
export class GetEmployeesFilterDto extends BaseQueryFilterDto{
    @IsOptional()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    search:string;

    @IsOptional()
    primarySupervisorId:string;

}
```

Running the following request http://localhost:3000/employee?batch=30 would throw the following exception:

```
[Nest] 27920   - 02/14/2020, 6:29:54 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot assign to read only property 'batch' of object '#<GetEmployeesFilterDto>' +606974ms
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'batch' of object '#<GetEmployeesFilterDto>'
    at _loop_1 (C:\ng-proj\nestjs-tutorial\node_modules\class-transformer\TransformOperationExecutor.js:242:47)
    at TransformOperationExecutor.transform (C:\ng-proj\nestjs-tutorial\node_modules\class-transformer\TransformOperationExecutor.js:260:17)
    at ClassTransformer.plainToClass (C:\ng-proj\nestjs-tutorial\node_modules\class-transformer\ClassTransformer.js:17:25)    at Object.plainToClass (C:\ng-proj\nestjs-tutorial\node_modules\class-transformer\index.js:20:29)
    at ValidationPipe.transform (C:\ng-proj\nestjs-tutorial\node_modules\@nestjs\common\pipes\validation.pipe.js:55:41)
    at transforms.reduce (C:\ng-proj\nestjs-tutorial\node_modules\@nestjs\core\pipes\pipes-consumer.js:15:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

However, when i move all the properties from the super class to GetEmployeesFilterDto like so:

```
export class GetEmployeesFilterDto extends BaseQueryFilterDto{
    @IsOptional()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    search:string;

    @IsOptional()
    primarySupervisorId:string;

    //Moved from BaseQueryFilterDto
    @IsOptional()
    @IsInt()
    @UsePipes(ParseIntPipe)
    batch:number;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsInt()
    @UsePipes(ParseIntPipe)
    skip:number;

}
```

The request runs successfully. 
Am I missing out something here or can I not implement inheritance to controller DTOs in NestJs?

Comment: That looks like a `class-transformer` issue from the stacktrace. Can you try reaching out to `class-transformer` for help?

Comment: Why do you have `@UsePipes()` on properties you are defining? That decorator is for controllers, controller methods, and controller method parameters only

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, Without the ParseIntPipe, the IsInt validation will fail since all values from querystrings are strings. Perhaps this is the wrong way to parseInt on properties of DTOs. Sorry, I'm very new to NestJs

Comment: @vinnyo why not use the `@Type()` transform from `class-trasnformer` as a part of your validation process, that way after validation it will also be parsed and you aren't using `@UsePipe()` in a weird place?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, Initially, I tried using `@Type()` and I was getting a validation error. But I realize now that I shouldn't need to add `@IsInt()` validation decorator with `@Type()`. Will update my post with the answer. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JayMcDoniel for pointing out that I shouldn't be using `@UsePipes()` on properties.

Here's the solution that works fine for me.

```
export class BaseQueryFilterDto{

    @IsOptional()
    @Type(() => Number)
    batch:number;

    @IsOptional()
    @Type(() => Number)
    skip:number;

}
```